# Razor Syntax Dynamically Name HTML Elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a form that creates a number of checkbox elements using Razor code like this

```
   foreach (var tag in Model.Tags)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@tag.ID" name="@tag.ID" value="@tag.TagName"/>@tag.TagName<br /
    }
```

This works but I want the ID's and names to be in this format chkTag[TagID] I've tried this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTag@tag.ID" name="chkTag@tag.ID" value="@tag.TagName"/>
```

but Razor just treats the whole thing as string and names them chkTag@tag.ID.

So I guess my question is how do I add the dynamic razor ID to the end of my Name and ID's?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you use `Html.CheckBoxFor`, and specify the `name` html attribute? and furthermore, use an editor template and save the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use parentheses around `tag.ID`, like this:

```
chkTag@(tag.ID)
```

Full code:

```
foreach (var tag in Model.Tags)
{
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTag@(tag.ID)" name="chkTag@(tag.ID)" value="@tag.TagName"/>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count(); i++)
{

        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Tags[i])

}
```

This should do it normally. It will automatically give the correct name.